# phpcs works, but output many error with it

Tags: php, composer-php, phpcodesniffer, phpcs

In my project i use `composer phpcs` to test my code style `phpcs --standard=PSR12 src/ tests/` and it's work well, all error are outputs. For example:

```
FILE: /home/user/PhpstormProjects/php-vadzim-yanushchyk/src/Task11/fibonacciNumber.php
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FOUND 1 ERROR AFFECTING 1 LINE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 35 | ERROR | [x] Expected 1 newline at end of file; 0 found
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PHPCBF CAN FIX THE 1 MARKED SNIFF VIOLATIONS AUTOMATICALLY
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Time: 99ms; Memory: 8MB
```

But also i receive many error with it.

```
PHP ParseError:  Unclosed '(' in  on line 1
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/user/PhpstormProjects/php-vadzim-yanushchyk/vendor/bin/phpcs:0
PHP   2. include() /home/user/PhpstormProjects/php-vadzim-yanushchyk/vendor/bin/phpcs:117
PHP   3. PHP_CodeSniffer\Runner->runPHPCS() /home/user/PhpstormProjects/php-vadzim-yanushchyk/vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/bin/phpcs:18
PHP   4. PHP_CodeSniffer\Runner->init() /home/user/PhpstormProjects/php-vadzim-yanushchyk/vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/src/Runner.php:70
PHP   5. PHP_CodeSniffer\Ruleset->__construct($config = class PHP_CodeSniffer\Config { private $settings = ['files' => [...], 'standards' => [...], 'verbosity' => 0, 'interactive' => FALSE, 'parallel' => 1, 'cache' => FALSE, 'cacheFile' => NULL, 'colors' => FALSE, 'explain' => FALSE, 'local' => FALSE, 'showSources' => FALSE, 'showProgress' => FALSE, 'quiet' => FALSE, 'annotations' => TRUE, 'tabWidth' => 4, 'encoding' => 'utf-8', 'extensions' => [...], 'sniffs' => [...], 'exclude' => [...], 'ignored' => [...], 'reportFile' => NULL, 'generator' => NULL, 'filter' => NULL, 'bootstrap' => [...], 'reports' => [...], 'basepath' => NULL, 'reportWidth' => 232, 'errorSeverity' => 5, 'warningSeverity' => 5, 'recordErrors' => TRUE, 'suffix' => '', 'stdin' => FALSE, 'stdinContent' => NULL, 'stdinPath' => NULL, 'unknown' => [...]]; public $dieOnUnknownArg = TRUE; private $cliArgs = [0 => '--tab-width=4'] }) /home/user/PhpstormProjects/php-vadzim-yanushchyk/vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/src/Runner.php:332
PHP   6. PHP_CodeSniffer\Ruleset->populateTokenListeners() /home/user/PhpstormProjects/php-vadzim-yanushchyk/vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/src/Ruleset.php:218
PHP   7. PHP_CodeSniffer\Sniffs\AbstractPatternSniff->register() /home/user/PhpstormProjects/php-vadzim-yanushchyk/vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/src/Ruleset.php:1230
PHP   8. PHP_CodeSniffer\Sniffs\AbstractPatternSniff->parse($pattern = 'function abc(...);') /home/user/PhpstormProjects/php-vadzim-yanushchyk/vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/src/Sniffs/AbstractPatternSniff.php:90
PHP   9. PHP_CodeSniffer\Sniffs\AbstractPatternSniff->createTokenPattern($str = '(') /home/user/PhpstormProjects/php-vadzim-yanushchyk/vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/src/Sniffs/AbstractPatternSniff.php:824
PHP  10. PHP_CodeSniffer\Tokenizers\Tokenizer->__construct($content = '<?php (?>', $config = NULL, $eolChar = *uninitialized*) /home/user/PhpstormProjects/php-vadzim-yanushchyk/vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/src/Sniffs/AbstractPatternSniff.php:916
PHP  11. PHP_CodeSniffer\Tokenizers\PHP->tokenize($string = '<?php (?>') /home/user/PhpstormProjects/php-vadzim-yanushchyk/vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/src/Tokenizers/Tokenizer.php:90
PHP  12. token_get_all($code = '<?php (?>') /home/user/PhpstormProjects/php-vadzim-yanushchyk/vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/src/Tokenizers/PHP.php:509
PHP ParseError:  Unclosed '(' in  on line 1
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/user/PhpstormProjects/php-vadzim-yanushchyk/vendor/bin/phpcs:0
PHP   2. include() /home/user/PhpstormProjects/php-vadzim-yanushchyk/vendor/bin/phpcs:117
PHP   3. PHP_CodeSniffer\Runner->runPHPCS() /home/user/PhpstormProjects/php-vadzim-yanushchyk/vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/bin/phpcs:18
PHP   4. PHP_CodeSniffer\Runner->init() /home/user/PhpstormProjects/php-vadzim-yanushchyk/vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/src/Runner.php:70
PHP   5. PHP_CodeSniffer\Ruleset->__construct($config = class PHP_CodeSniffer\Config { private $settings = ['files' => [...], 'standards' => [...], 'verbosity' => 0, 'interactive' => FALSE, 'parallel' => 1, 'cache' => FALSE, 'cacheFile' => NULL, 'colors' => FALSE, 'explain' => FALSE, 'local' => FALSE, 'showSources' => FALSE, 'showProgress' => FALSE, 'quiet' => FALSE, 'annotations' => TRUE, 'tabWidth' => 4, 'encoding' => 'utf-8', 'extensions' => [...], 'sniffs' => [...], 'exclude' => [...], 'ignored' => [...], 'reportFile' => NULL, 'generator' => NULL, 'filter' => NULL, 'bootstrap' => [...], 'reports' => [...], 'basepath' => NULL, 'reportWidth' => 232, 'errorSeverity' => 5, 'warningSeverity' => 5, 'recordErrors' => TRUE, 'suffix' => '', 'stdin' => FALSE, 'stdinContent' => NULL, 'stdinPath' => NULL, 'unknown' => [...]]; public $dieOnUnknownArg = TRUE; private $cliArgs = [0 => '--tab-width=4'] }) /home/user/PhpstormProjects/php-vadzim-yanushchyk/vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/src/Runner.php:332
PHP   6. PHP_CodeSniffer\Ruleset->populateTokenListeners() /home/user/PhpstormProjects/php-vadzim-yanushchyk/vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/src/Ruleset.php:218
PHP   7. PHP_CodeSniffer\Sniffs\AbstractPatternSniff->register() /home/user/PhpstormProjects/php-vadzim-yanushchyk/vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/src/Ruleset.php:1230
PHP   8. PHP_CodeSniffer\Sniffs\AbstractPatternSniff->parse($pattern = 'function abc(...)') /home/user/PhpstormProjects/php-vadzim-yanushchyk/vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/src/Sniffs/AbstractPatternSniff.php:90
PHP   9. PHP_CodeSniffer\Sniffs\AbstractPatternSniff->createTokenPattern($str = '(') /home/user/PhpstormProjects/php-vadzim-yanushchyk/vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/src/Sniffs/AbstractPatternSniff.php:824
PHP  10. PHP_CodeSniffer\Tokenizers\Tokenizer->__construct($content = '<?php (?>', $config = NULL, $eolChar = *uninitialized*) /home/user/PhpstormProjects/php-vadzim-yanushchyk/vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/src/Sniffs/AbstractPatternSniff.php:916
PHP  11. PHP_CodeSniffer\Tokenizers\PHP->tokenize($string = '<?php (?>') /home/user/PhpstormProjects/php-vadzim-yanushchyk/vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/src/Tokenizers/Tokenizer.php:90
PHP  12. token_get_all($code = '<?php (?>') /home/user/PhpstormProjects/php-vadzim-yanushchyk/vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/src/Tokenizers/PHP.php:509
PHP ParseError:  Unclosed '(' in  on line 1
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/user/PhpstormProjects/php-vadzim-yanushchyk/vendor/bin/phpcs:0
PHP   2. include() /home/user/PhpstormProjects/php-vadzim-yanushchyk/vendor/bin/phpcs:117
PHP   3. PHP_CodeSniffer\Runner->runPHPCS() /home/user/PhpstormProjects/php-vadzim-yanushchyk/vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/bin/phpcs:18
PHP   4. PHP_CodeSniffer\Runner->init() /home/user/PhpstormProjects/php-vadzim-yanushchyk/vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/src/Runner.php:70
PHP   5. PHP_CodeSniffer\Ruleset->__construct($config = class PHP_CodeSniffer\Config { private $settings = ['files' => [...], 'standards' => [...], 'verbosity' => 0, 'interactive' => FALSE, 'parallel' => 1, 'cache' => FALSE, 'cacheFile' => NULL, 'colors' => FALSE, 'explain' => FALSE, 'local' => FALSE, 'showSources' => FALSE, 'showProgress' => FALSE, 'quiet' => FALSE, 'annotations' => TRUE, 'tabWidth' => 4, 'encoding' => 'utf-8', 'extensions' => [...], 'sniffs' => [...], 'exclude' => [...], 'ignored' => [...], 'reportFile' => NULL, 'generator' => NULL, 'filter' => NULL, 'bootstrap' => [...], 'reports' => [...], 'basepath' => NULL, 'reportWidth' => 232, 'errorSeverity' => 5, 'warningSeverity' => 5, 'recordErrors' => TRUE, 'suffix' => '', 'stdin' => FALSE, 'stdinContent' => NULL, 'stdinPath' => NULL, 'unknown' => [...]]; public $dieOnUnknownArg = TRUE; private $cliArgs = [0 => '--tab-width=4'] }) /home/user/PhpstormProjects/php-vadzim-yanushchyk/vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/src/Runner.php:332
PHP   6. PHP_CodeSniffer\Ruleset->populateTokenListeners() /home/user/PhpstormProjects/php-vadzim-yanushchyk/vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/src/Ruleset.php:218
PHP   7. PHP_CodeSniffer\Sniffs\AbstractPatternSniff->register() /home/user/PhpstormProjects/php-vadzim-yanushchyk/vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/src/Ruleset.php:1230
PHP   8. PHP_CodeSniffer\Sniffs\AbstractPatternSniff->parse($pattern = 'abstract function abc(...);') /home/user/PhpstormProjects/php-vadzim-yanushchyk/vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/src/Sniffs/AbstractPatternSniff.php:90
PHP   9. PHP_CodeSniffer\Sniffs\AbstractPatternSniff->createTokenPattern($str = '(') /home/user/PhpstormProjects/php-vadzim-yanushchyk/vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/src/Sniffs/AbstractPatternSniff.php:824
PHP  10. PHP_CodeSniffer\Tokenizers\Tokenizer->__construct($content = '<?php (?>', $config = NULL, $eolChar = *uninitialized*) /home/user/PhpstormProjects/php-vadzim-yanushchyk/vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/src/Sniffs/AbstractPatternSniff.php:916
PHP  11. PHP_CodeSniffer\Tokenizers\PHP->tokenize($string = '<?php (?>') /home/user/PhpstormProjects/php-vadzim-yanushchyk/vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/src/Tokenizers/Tokenizer.php:90
PHP  12. token_get_all($code = '<?php (?>') /home/user/PhpstormProjects/php-vadzim-yanushchyk/vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/src/Tokenizers/PHP.php:509
```

How i can fix this problem? I have this error only on my computer, tests of github cs, lint when i push changes are successful.

Comment: The call to `token_get_all()` uses the error suppression operator `@` specifically to catch and handle these sort of syntax errors. If you're only getting this error on your local machine, you may have done something to stop the error suppression operator working, like using a PHP extension that can do so.

Comment: @Vadim did you resolve this issue?